# Allow all projects in an organization to consume organization-scoped feed

Tags: maven, azure-devops

In our AzDO organization, we have an organization-scoped feed, that was created to be usde by all projects. But for every new project we create, we have to go to its "Artifacts" page, open Settings / Permissions for that feed and in the dot-menu click "Allow project-scoped builds".
Otherwise maven gives us an exception like this:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project PROJECT: Could not resolve dependencies for project GROUP:ARTIFACT:VERSION: Failed to collect dependencies at GROUP:ARTIFACT:VERSION: Failed to read artifact descriptor for GROUP:ARTIFACT:VERSION: Could not transfer artifact GROUP:ARTIFACT:VERSION from/to MY-FEED (https://ORGANIZATION.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/repo/maven/v1): Authorization failed for https://ORGANIZATION.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/repo/maven/v1/GROUP/ARTIFACT/VERSION/....pom 403 Forbidden - User 'GUID' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'ReadPackages'. (DevOps Activity ID: GUID2) -> [Help 1]

Can't we set it up so that all projects - past, present and future - will have access to the feed?

Comment: Strongly recommend to use a repository manager makes it easier...

Comment: @khmarbaise You mean I should not use Azure DevOps feed? If so, why?

Comment: The usual way: You run a Nexus or Artifactory in your company which handles all the Java artifacts, as khmarbaise said. They are made for usage with Maven.

Comment: @JFabianMeier Well, AzDO's feeds are also made for usage with Maven (and Nuget, and...), and in fact they do work. Has anyone of you complainants actually tried to use it? The only problem I have is this per-project permissioning. Nothing that shouldn't be fixable.

Comment: I am not saying that your solution will not work. I just wanted to point out that the vast majority of organisations which use Maven uses either Nexus or Artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

The Organization Scope feed can be used for the entire organization.

But in `Project Settings -> Settings` , there is an option: "**Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines**".

When this option is enable , the authorization scope is limited to the Project level. This option is enable by default for projects.

[image]

It could be the root cause of the 403 error.

Since this option is enabled by default in new projects, you need to manually disable this option to use the organization scope feed.

Based on  the time being, there seems to be no way to automatically turn off this option in new projects.

The steps to disable this option:

1. Disable the option in **Organizaiton Settings ->  Settings.**
2. Disable the option in Target Project.

By the way, in Organization scope feed, you also need to make sure that the role `Project Collection Build Service(Organizaiton name)` has permission. This role has the `Contributor` permission by default.

[image]

Comment: Do I understand you right that this answer says that it is **not** possible to enable it for all projects, once and for all, like I want in my question?

Comment: Yes. You are right. I understand your requirements.  Since this option is enabled by default for new projects, there is no option could disable it for all projects. You can test this option to check if it is the same as what I said. Thanks.

Comment: If this option is disable, although you don't set ‘Allow project-scoped builds’, you could also be able to use this feed.

Comment: I can confirm that the "Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines" setting is on (by default)

Comment: Hi @EugeneBeresovsky. Due to this default setting, I think there is no once and for all method.  But you can consider disabling this option manually.

Comment: As I have to do that for every project - what have I gained, compared to doing enabling "Allow project-scoped builds" per project, which I am doing now?

Comment: The most direct difference to feed: "Allow project-scoped builds" in feed settings is for the current feed. If you create a new feed or use other existing feed, you still need to enable this option. But "Limit job authorization scope..." is for all feed, if this option is disabled, you could use all organization scope feeds.

Comment: Here are docs about these two options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#package-permissions-in-azure-pipelines and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/options?view=azure-devops#scoped-build-identities